# Person going through giyur le'chumrah obligated to sell chametz?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, selling-mechirat-chametz

I know someone who needs a Giyur le'chumrah and was asked by his rabbi to SELL (NOT to buy) his chametz before Pessach.

I thought that selling chametz is only for yehudim.

Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person who is undergoing a Giyur le'chumrah may be Jewish. The reason for doing this is because we cannot be sure that he is Jewish. Thus, just in case he might be Jewish, he sells the chametz so as not to violate the halacha. A giyur le'chumrah means that he undergoes a conversion on the assumption that if he is really Jewish, nothing has needed to be done and he is still Jewish. If he was not Jewish, then he becomes Jewish. Similarly, if he was not Jewish, nothing needed to be done with the chametz, but the sale does not hurt. If he was Jewish, then he had to sell the chametz by halacha.